# Stylebot extension: adding access keys for jquery?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, javascript, css, jquery

Is it possible to use a program like Stylebot to have a custom CSS rule which activates a region when a number is pressed?  I want 1 to click region 1, 2 to "right-click" region 2, and 3 to click region 3.  I'm looking at the css, and it seems like there's a div whose third-order descendants are controls for a .js script.  They are `<p>` elements, and they are all of the same class.  They do not have id's.

I'm thinking it would be incredibly complex....  Maybe I could just write a mouseclick script.  On the other hand, could it be as simple as writing an `accesskey` tag in, properly, to these regions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is with Tampermonkey.

Since you want to extend a functionality of a website with actions that respond to what user does, you will need some javascript.

Stylebot is for custom CSS, Tampermonkey is for custom JavaScript. I'm not that good in JS to help you, though.